# How to parse an input piece by piece with ANTLR?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I am parsing an input that is **unknown**, so the parser might fail, but I want to **parse it as much as possible**.

Also, the input can be **very big** *(> 1 Go)*.

Let's say the parser parses **items** *(represented by letters)* and this is the input :

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

1. I want to parse this input **piece by piece**. I can't give it the entire input because :

- it can be **too big**
- a failure at an item could provoke failures on the item(s) following.

2. I don't want to **cut the input arbitrarily** because :

- If I **cut at the wrong place**, it will create errors *(cutting in the middle of B for example)*.
- If I try to not cut at the wrong place, I end up **"preparsing" the input**. *(preparsing means that I will have the same issues for the preparsing as I have for the parsing, and the grammar is complex, items can be nested, so preparsing is complicated)*

3. My current solution is to **setup my grammar** this way :

```
blind_parsing
    : blind_statement swallow_to_eof
    ;

swallow_to_eof
    : ~(EOF)*
    ;
```

The parser **parses ONE item** and **swallows the rest in the rule swallow_to_eof**.
I give the parser a partial input and complete it, piece by piece.

I don't like this solution :

- the items can vary greatly *(thousands to millions of characters)*, so **I give the parser big pieces** to make sure I don't accidentally cut the biggest items in two.
- the **performances are poor** :

  - the size of the parsing inputs are big *(previous point)*
  - we keep parsing the same elements, dumping them in the swallow_to_eof rule *(the example above is parsed in 5 times if everything goes well, and that sounds very inefficient :*

    - A BCDE
    - B CDE
    - C DE
    - D E
    - E

Maybe there is an obvious solution to this issue and I missed it.
How do you solve this problem ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as *incremental parsing* and no, ANTLR4 does not support this out of the box. In the past there were a number of discussions about this matter, but I don't remember having seen a reliable solution yet.

Comment: "ANTLR4 does not support this out of the box"
Thanks for the answer, that was exactly what I was wandering : if there was an ANTLR4 solution to this or if it has to be solved "from the outside".

Now I know the coined term for this. It will make my searches much more efficient.

Cheers !